# AndEngine Text component customization

Tags: android, text, andengine

I want to create `Text` AndEngine component with some custom settings:
1. Center Horizontal Align
2. Dark background
3. Custom round border

I've tried:

```
Text text = new Text(0, 120, mFont, "", 100, new TextOptions(AutoWrap.NONE, 0, HorizontalAlign.CENTER, Text.LEADING_DEFAULT), getVertexBufferObjectManager());
text.setColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
text.setText("Test")
```

but nothing works, the text is aligned to left, and background wasn't changed. And I've didn't found any info about border setting.

Please help me, I'm new in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Color set's the texts color, not the background. For changing the background color I suggest that you draw a rectangle and attach the text to it.

As far as I remember, horizontal align is working only when AutoWrap isn't none.

I don't know if custom border is possible with andEngine's text class, but maybe you can give a try for the StrokeFont (which is a subclass of the Font) class.